# How to compute level values for dynlm output wth regressison using differenced series

Tags: r

I have used the dynlm function to regress a differenced series as the dependent variable and its 5 lags as the regressors. The summary output file is attached. Can someone help me compute the level fitted values from the summary output. I have also attached the data frame showing the values of residuals and the fitted values based on the above regression?

**Summary Output**

```
Time series regression with "ts" data:
Start = 6, End = 364

Call:
dynlm(formula = dusagets ~ (L(dusagets, 1:5)))

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-6915.9  -748.9    20.7   822.1  6099.6 

Coefficients:
                   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)       -41.24158   88.26414  -0.467 0.640608    
L(dusagets, 1:5)1  -0.19753    0.05231  -3.776 0.000187 ***
L(dusagets, 1:5)2  -0.43436    0.05311  -8.179 5.22e-15 ***
L(dusagets, 1:5)3  -0.15207    0.05729  -2.654 0.008305 ** 
L(dusagets, 1:5)4  -0.14216    0.05292  -2.687 0.007561 ** 
L(dusagets, 1:5)5  -0.17909    0.05243  -3.415 0.000711 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1671 on 353 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.1858,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1743 
F-statistic: 16.11 on 5 and 353 DF,  p-value: 2.602e-14
```

P.S
How do I attach a file. Wanted to attach the file with the residuals and the fitted values from the regression but don't know how!

Best regards

Deepak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By working with differences all what is lost is the *initial* level of a series. Here's an example how to come back to levels where the situation is additionally complicated by introducing lagged terms.

```
y <- log10(UKDriverDeaths)
dy <- diff(y)
m <- dynlm(dy ~ L(dy, 1) + L(dy, 12))
```

Now `fitted(m)` has fitted values for differences and the only thing missing is to know where to start from. In particular, we have that

```
cumsum(fitted(m)) + y[1 + 12]
```

are values that can be compared to the initial series in levels,

```
tail(y, -(1 + 12))
```

where we lose 1 observation due to taking differences and another 12 correspond to the maximal lag.

---

Now why does `cumsum(fitted(m)) + y[1 + 12]` give the desired result? In general, let the observed series in levels be y<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>2</sub>, ... and the one in differences be Δy<sub>2</sub>, Δy<sub>3</sub>, ..., where notice that we don't have Δy<sub>1</sub> due to absence of y<sub>0</sub>.

Now forgetting about lags and just thinking about the role of `cumsum`, notice that

y<sub>t</sub> = (y<sub>t</sub>-y<sub>t-1</sub>) + (y<sub>t-1</sub>-y<sub>t-2</sub>) + ... + (y<sub>2</sub>-y<sub>1</sub>) + y<sub>1</sub> = Δy<sub>t</sub> + Δy<sub>t-1</sub> + ... + Δy<sub>2</sub> + y<sub>1</sub>.

That is, by summing all the changes from the beginning until the period t, we first get the aggregate change y<sub>t</sub>-y<sub>1</sub>, and then as to get y<sub>t</sub> we also add y<sub>1</sub> - the starting level.

By using `cumsum` we accumulate those changes for each t in a vectorized fashion, and then we add y<sub>13</sub> to the whole vector `cumsum(fitted(m))` because they all have the same starting point of interest, y<sub>13</sub>.

Comment: Hi Julius -> Wouldn't fitted values start from 13th value if we are working with L(duk, 12)?  So how would then cumsum(c(0, fitted(dfm)) fill the 1st 12 values with zeros? Wouldn't it only add 1 zero value to ftted values vector.? Or is my understanding flawed?

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal, right, I completely forgot the lags, hopefully now it's right.

Comment: -> Must be correct now! I will test it once I get back home. At work now! Thanks! Will keep you posted.

Comment: -> Just realized that this will only give me the fitted values for the differenced series, not the level values). I am after the level values. Granted, these can be computed using the parameter estimates and the first principles by long hand, just wondering if there is a way to get this information using an available R function as it would be reasonably complicated doing it by long hanc for my original scenario with 5 lags of the differenced series?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. In my example `tail(uk, -(1 + 12))` are levels and `cumsum(fitted(dfm)) + uk[1 + 12]` are fitted values for the differenced series *transformed* into a series of levels. Hence, I understand that the latter series is what you are after.

Comment: -> Sorry about the confusion. Wouldn't tail(uk, -(1 + 12)) will give me the original level values - not the fitted level values. I refer to fitted values as those that are calculated based on the regression parameter estimates. So could you please elaborate how does cumsum(fitted(dfm)) transform the fitted differenced values to fitted level values - maybe I don't understand how cumsum() works.

Comment: -> Thanks for the explanation! I will have to try it out or desk check it! I am sure its correct but I need to do it that way to get my head around it! Will let you know how I went. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal, sure. As a numerical example, consider (5,6,7,8,9). Differencing gives (1,1,1,1). Applying `cumsum` to the latter vector gives (1,2,3,4), which contains all the dynamics of the initial vector, but doesn't know the right start. Adding 5 then gives (6,7,8,9) again. (As I did before, you may add also a zero, as in (0,1,2,3,4), as to have another observation.)

Comment: -> I checked it and works just as you said. Thanks also for the additonal explanation. Whilst I have got you, why  does my initial call 'dynlm(formula = dusagets ~ (L(dusagets, 1:5)))' only works with 'ts' data set and not with 'xts' dataset. I tried like tihs and it failed : "dynlm(formula = dusagets ~ (L(coredata(dusagets), 1:5)))" and it complained - still wondering why? Any suggestions? By the way, how do you get the '@' at the beginning?

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal, `?dynlm` says that the data has to be `ts` or `zoo`, so that's how it is; if you want to go deeper, then you need to ask a new question. I wrote the @ by hand, to make sure that you get notified about my comment.